# Cordova - Open add contact dialog without contacts permission

Tags: cordova, contacts

Is there a way to launch the Add Contact dialog with pre-filled details without the contacts permission. I don't want the app to have the Contacts permission for privacy reasons, and I'm happy for the user to have to explicitly save the details.

For example, when I have a "tel:..." URI, it pops up the dialer, but the user still needs to hit the dial button.

Comment: I am suprised that there not easy way :/ the contacts plugin permmission are scary